# Magento product listing

Tags: php, magento

the developer created a custom module on my magento website that lists the least expensive product from every category on the page.

It's great but now the page is too long with additional content added. How can I limit the number of categories displayed to say 10, or even better - to 10 that I can specify the order to?

In other words I want to display everything in the same fashion but limit number of categories to 10 and specify the order of them by using category id.

Here's the original code:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$helperOutput = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
$categories = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, true);
?>
<div class="specials_list">
<?
// Iterate all categories in store
foreach ($categories as $curr){

    // If category is Active
    if($curr->getIsActive()){
        $info = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($curr->getId());

        $product = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addCategoryFilter($info)->addAttributeToSelect('small_image');
        $product->addMinimalPrice();
        $product->getSelect()->order("price", "ASC")->limit(1);
        $product->load();
        foreach($product as $temp){}
        $product = $temp;
        if($product){
            ?>
            <div class="product">
                <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($curr)?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(135, 135); ?>" width="135" alt="<?php echo $product->getName() ?>" />
                    <div class="price">From <span class="amount"><? echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(),true,false); ?></span></div>
                    <div class="view">View All &gt;&gt;</div>
                    <div class="name"><?php echo strtoupper($curr->getName()); ?></div>

                </a>
            </div>
            <?
        }           
    }
}
?>
<br class="clear"/>
</div>
```

I've tried to slice the array but apparently it is not a normal array. Also trying to use for loop instead foreach gave me no positive result.

Would you please have any ideas to how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the number of rows within your foreach loop and exit or continue when you reached the number you want?